# Error message on nonexistent home dir (pam.d/* settings)

Tags: debian, pam, ldap

I have a host running Debian 8.  I set LDAP authentication, but the home directory is not created.  I added in common-session:

```
session optional        pam_systemd.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0077
```

It didn't help, so I tried adding in common-account:

```
session    required   pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022
```

This also didn't work.  I still get the error:

```
ssh user.name@192.168.250.30
Last login: Wed Oct 12 01:54:59 2016 from 192.168.70.96
Could not chdir to home directory /home/user.name: No such file or directory
```

I've looked at the manual, but haven't found the answer:

**How can I prevent this error message?**

**SOLVED**

In /etc/ssh/ssh_config edit UsePAM yes

Comment: In one environment I work in, there are no home directories, and you get this error message any time you log in to any server.  It doesn't harm anything; it's just noise.  You can ignore it.  (But I *would* be interested in the config options to avoid this noise....)

Comment: @Nikita check the `UsePAM` option in /etc/ssh/sshd_conf on that server, is it yes, or no?

Comment: @Wildcard I believe that without (auto)creating (temporary)homes at remote site it is not possible to get rid of that message

Comment: @Serge, man, i idiot.  I writing "UsePAM no" in playbook ansible and forgot it. THANKS! I write yes and it work!

Comment: @Serge, care to make that an answer?  :)

Comment: @Wildcard I believe that exercise would serve better for Nikita ;)

Comment: @Nikita write an answer yourself and I will up vote it!